# When does changing image width by jQuery preserve size ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a JS function which changes sizes of images and their positions. The function is called when page is loaded or resized.

```
function resizer(){
//A.
jQuery("#imageid").width(x);
...
//B.
jQuery("#imageid").width(jQuery("#imageid").width() * y);
//where x and y are fixed values.
}

jQuery(window).load(function() {
resizer();
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
resizer();
});
```

In both lines A and B, i do not change heights of images directly.
Why both lines of code do not change the size ratios of images when the function is called on window load, but change size ratios of images  when the function is called on window resize ?
If I add jQuery("#imageid").height() for each line, size ratios are kept when the function is called on window resize. but not kept when called on window load.

Comment: You can use resizeable() aspect ratio function in jquery UI.
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
aspectRatio: true
});

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: It's not because of how jQuery works but it's about of HTML. If only one dimension is set before image loads, the second dimension is changed to keep size ratio. After image loads, height and width are defined, so changing one won't change second one.

Comment: Sorry, but here the function works the same way both on load and on resize.
http://jsfiddle.net/rhjbvrgm/3/